# In c++, Does it make sense to prohibit copy construction if the default construction is prohibited in the first place?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor, default-constructor

I was going through a code implementation where the intention was to not let anyone make objects of a particular class. Here is the code snippet:

```
class CantInstantiate
{
    CantInstantiate();
    CantInstantiate(const CantInstantiate&);
    ...
};
```

Is it really required to make the copy constructor private undefined if the default constructor is already made private undefined (provided there is no other constructor)? What is the benefit of preventing copy of an object when we don't have an original object in the first place? Please explain. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be better to make the copy ctor `= delete;` rather than the old "private and unimplemented" hack.

Comment: Oh, I realize your default constructor is not only private but also undefined, and there is no other ctor. Your class will only have static members and serves basically as a namespace. In that case there cannot be any objects and I don't see a reason (besides documenting intent in the code, which is a good thing) to delete the copy ctor.

Answer (score 0):

If the intent is to prevent making instances of a class then you need to ensure you can't call any constructor. If you don't explicitly prohibit copy construction then you're leaving it up to the compiler to decide whether to include one or not, based on the conditions for causing a **[deleted implicitly-declared copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor)** which are:

> ```
> - T has non-static data members that cannot be copied (have deleted, inaccessible, or ambiguous copy constructors);
> - T has direct or virtual base class that cannot be copied (has deleted, inaccessible, or ambiguous copy constructors);
> - T has direct or virtual base class with a deleted or inaccessible destructor; 
> - T is a union-like class and has a variant member with non-trivial copy constructor;
> - T has a data member of rvalue reference type;
> - T has a user-defined move constructor or move assignment operator (this condition only causes the implicitly-declared, not the defaulted, copy constructor to be deleted).
> ```

So if we assume that you have a class A that attempts to prevent itself being constructed by only prohibiting default construction and not including anything in the list above, it's possible to exploit the implicit copy constructor to gain an instance of A, or even to inherit from it. For example:

```
class A
{
    A(){};
};

struct B : public A {
    B() : A(*a)
    {}
    A* a;
};

B b;
A a (*static_cast<A*>(nullptr));
```

Now admittedly the code above could produce unexpected behaviour and any decent compiler would produce warnings if you attempted to do it but it does compile. The practicality of such an approach would depend entirely upon what else was declared within A...

I would argue that if the idea is to stop creation then you need to ensure that all methods of construction are prevented. Therefore, it's a much better approach to explicitly delete the: default constructor, copy constructor and move constructor. This sends a much clearer statement of intent and I believe it should prevent all methods of construction.

```
class CantInstantiate
{
public:
    CantInstantiate() = delete;
    CantInstantiate(const CantInstantiate&) = delete;
    CantInstantiate(CantInstantiate&&) = delete;
    ...
};
```

Comment: While explicitly deleting them may be clearer and better maintainable I think it is not *necessary*. Your example is invalid -- of course you can cast anything to anything, proving nothing. There'll never be an `A`, and consequently you won't ever be able to call the copy ctor on one, deleted or not.

Comment: Then you should probably delete the move constructor and perhaps the assignment operator (your left hand side could also be a fake ref, while you are at it!). Perhaps we should also delete the destructor (is that possible?). Just to be sure ;-).

Comment: I disagree with your first comment. The purpose of the cast was to produce input acceptable to the copy constructor. This means a constructor has been called on A and therefore we have an instance of A. I accept that casting nullptr to a reference is undefined behaviour. I was only trying to demonstrate that if you don't explicitly prevent it then it could be exploited.

Comment: I agree the move constructor should be added, I edited the post. [Implicit copy assignment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment) should be prevented by declaring the move constructor. [Implicit move assignment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment) is prevented by defining the constructors. It's possible to delete the destructor as well but I don't think it adds anything as if you can't construct it then there is nothing to prevent deletion of.